# I keep getting a security pop-up. How to get rid of it?

Tags: security, popup

I keep getting the pop-up that says it is McAfee
but it looks scammy. I don't have McFee,
I just use Windows 10 Security.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have performed a full scan, and it says
"No action needed" but the pop up keeps coming and
getting in the way.

How do I get rid of this?

Many thanks.
Dave
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tppwF.png